# IIS 7.5 memory and performance problems

Tags: asp.net, iis

I used to have my application in iis 6 and the process w3wp consume max for 4Gb now am using the new version this amount has increased 2-3GB.
any recommended optimization configuration.?

Comment: Please be more specific... What type of application is that? Perhaps you could post some code? Where do you think the biggest load in the application comes from?

Nobody can really help you with such vague question.

My suggestion would be to first find what process exactly is eating all your ram, try following this tut: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jb/archive/2006/02/22/536693.aspx

When you know whats going on, please come back here and give us more details.

Good luck!

Comment: Maybe you use too much cache, or you forget to close objects. Think to check any tool to see what memory you forget to close.

Comment: no all unmanaged resources is being disposed and released from memory. the problem is with the configuration am sure because such problem didnt exist before that

Answer (score 0):

This articles might help you find a suitable solution:

[w3wp.exe using too much memory and resources](http://blog.whitesites.com/w3wp-exe-using-too-much-memory-and-resources__633900106668026886_blog.htm)

[Identifying Worker Process (w3wp.exe) – IIS 6.0 and IIS 7.0 for Debugging ASP.NET Application](http://abhijitjana.net/2010/07/15/identifying-worker-process-w3wp-exe-iis-6-0-and-iis-7-0-for-debugging-asp-net-application/)